# How do I realize communication between two processes in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, wcf, compact-framework, windows-ce, remoting

what is the best way to realize a communication between 2 processes? And how do I exchange Objects between both? I hoped that I can use something like WCF netNamedPipeBinding, in my understanding this is a way to realize something like this in the normal Framework but it looks like this is not implemented in the Compact framework 3.5 WCF?!

Can someone please give me a hint?

Thank you

twickl

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best mechanism for communicating cross-process in Windows CE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946279/what-is-the-best-mechanism-for-communicating-cross-process-in-windows-ce)

Comment: +1 for the amazingly well worded title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass objects between 2 processes in .Net CF using a WCF Service. However you can only use basicHttpBinding (but you can overcome that by using a SSL connection) and also to generate a WSDL proxy for the WCF service you cannot use the desktop version (SvcUtil.exe), you'll have to use NetCfSvcUtil.exe

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/09/13/calling-wcf-services-from-netcf-3-5-using-compact-wcf-and-netcfsvcutil-exe.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just for my understanding: I  use this for the communication between to processes on the same machine?!

Comment: Are you running .Net CF on a mobile device or on a desktop ?

Comment: On a Mobile Device! I have to applications on the same Device that have to communicate and exchange objects.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication

Answer (score 1):

Use plain Socket with a custom protocol.