# Send message from one process to other use winapi in wince

Tags: c#, winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best mechanism for communicating cross-process in Windows CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946279/what-is-the-best-mechanism-for-communicating-cross-process-in-windows-ce)

I created two apps using .net cf 2.0.

And I need send some message\command from one app to other (when second app receive this message I want run some code). How can I do this use only winapi. I don't want use tcp or wcf, only use winapi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try WM_COPYDATA in following link...it is a win32 api

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011.aspx

can be done also through named pipes & MSMQ

Comment: have you any example for this?

Comment: http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=536&ver=vcs